# ASP.Net core Identity - Overkill for basic login system?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I need to create a very basic log in system to allow access to an admin portal.

I'll need to hold email, password and a field to identify access level (admin, read-only or edit).

Users will be created by an admin, where they will get sent an email with a generated password. There will be no user registration page.

Asp.net core Identity would handle all this...but my question is it overkill for a small application?

Answer (score 0):

That is really a matter of opinion. I don't mind overkilling small tasks, as I learn a lot in the process. If it's a system between a small group, you could just implement a reset-button for you, that resets whoever you want, and generates a new random password. I have done that in the past.

Also .Net Core Identity handles a lot of the boilerplate code, so it's not that difficult to implement. There are a lot of great guides out there.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but my question is it overkill for a small application?

Depends on your definition of an overkill.

1. It will allow you to setup working identity system in a few clicks, so from that point of view, *having to code all that stuff from scratch would be an overkill.*
2. On the other hand, the generated tables have a few excess (for your use case) columns that might seem like an overkill. There is also support for functionality like 2FA, which you may not need.

Bottom line: by choosing to use the identity system, you save time and gain some extraneous functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using .net for a very long time, and for a long time implemented custom user management (overriding built in providers, and customising to my own database structures etc) This is required if implementing over legacy system but for new development and security, it worth using off-the-shelf authorization/authentication systems whether it's built in or supported by .Net or using 3rd party services.